# c# How do we give access to users from a dynamically generated google sheet?

Tags: c#, google-sheets

I' am creating dynamically some google sheet given an array of data on one of my endpoints.

it creates successfully, but when I open the generated url, I get the following:

[image]

The documentation is not very clear, but I wish to add permissions to a given domain (or set of people) every time I generate a new sheet.

code:

```
private static readonly string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Drive, SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };

public string Create(string templateName, List<IList<object>> values, int numberOfRows)
    {
        var sheetId = 0;
        var spreadSheetId = string.Empty;
        var initializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(SheetsOptionsConstants.ServiceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = Scopes
        }.FromPrivateKey(SheetsOptionsConstants.PrivateKey);

        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer);

        // Create Google Sheets API service.
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = applicationName
        });
       
        // Create a new sheet
        var sheetTitle = $"[{templateName}] {_clock.Now:yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm}";

        try
        {
            var sheet = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest
            {
                Requests = new List<Request>
                {
                    new Request
                    {
                        AddSheet = new AddSheetRequest
                        {
                            Properties= new SheetProperties
                            {
                                Title = sheetTitle
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var createRequest = new Spreadsheet
            {
                Properties = new SpreadsheetProperties
                {
                    Title = sheetTitle
                }
            };
            
            var spreadSheetCreate = service.Spreadsheets.Create(createRequest).Execute();
            spreadSheetId = spreadSheetCreate.SpreadsheetId;

            var request = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(sheet, spreadSheetId);
            var result = request.Execute();
            sheetId = result.Replies.First().AddSheet.Properties.SheetId.GetValueOrDefault(0);

            // Add data in sheet
            var range = $"'{sheetTitle}'!A1:X{numberOfRows + 1}";
            var valueRange = new ValueRange
            {
                Range = range,
                Values = values
            };

            var valuesRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange, spreadSheetId, range);
            valuesRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
            valuesRequest.Execute();

            _logger.LogInformation("Create sheet with name {sheetTitle} and {count} lines", sheetTitle, numberOfRows);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.LogError(exception, "Error to create sheet with name {sheetTitle}", sheetTitle);
        }

        return string.Format(TemplateUrl, spreadSheetId, sheetId);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Drive API to create the permissions for the Sheet. To do so, initialize the Drive Service and create a permissions object. Then, apply it to the Sheet Id using the method [create()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create).

You should include the following to your code:

```
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data; //This might be not necessary if you already use Drive.v3
```

The required scopes:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`

Create the [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create#request-body) object:

```
//(example to give writing permissions to a domain)
Permission perms = new Permission();
perms.Role = "writer";
perms.Type = "domain";
perms.Domain = "your_domain";
```

And then the request:

```
// Create Drive API service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
service.Permissions.Create(perms, sheetId).Execute();
```

**References:**

- [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet)
- [Manage sharing](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing)
- [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) from the Drive Api

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to implement this approach, but i am getting a The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable. [403] error. I created the sheet, and added a permission afterwards. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Nevermind, I was adding other parameters! it works, thanks!